# real purpose of moq framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I've been asked to write unit tests using Moq framework. I'm fairly new on how to write Moq tests in c#.

I'm going through this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx)

Here is what I'm doing right now as we are using dependency injection on repository

```
    //Repository
public interface IRepo
{
    IQueryable<MyModel> GetById( long userId );
}

public class Repo : BaseManager, IRepo
{
    public Repo(myDbContext context)
    {
        dbContext = context; //dbContext is from BaseManager class
    } 
    public IQueryable<MyModel> GetById( long userId )
    {
        return dbContext.MyModel.Where(x => x.IsActive && x.UserId == userId );
    }
}

//Test class
public class Test 
{
    Mock<DbSet<MyModel>> mockSet;
    Mock<myDbContext> mockContext;
    Mock<IRepo> mockRepository;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var data = new List<MyModel>{
            //3 records
        }.AsQueryable();

        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyModel>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<MyModel>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        var mockContext = new Mock<myDbContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.MyModel).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        mockRepository = new Mock<IRepo>();
        mockRepository.Setup(m => m.GetById(It.IsAny<long>())).Returns(data); //Here the GetById method is set to return all 3 records set in data object. 
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Mock_For_Nothing()
    {
        var controller = new MyController(mockRepository.Object);
        var result = controller.GetById(1); //this will call GetById method in the repository

        Assert.AreEqual(result.Count(), 1);//This will fail as we will get count as 3
    }
}
```

So, the logic in the repository is never executed though I mocked context and repository. As GetById method would directly return the result with 3 records as per dummy data.

I'm expecting the dummy data to be filtered out based on the logic in the repository method. Is this possible with Moq ?

What is the real purpose of using Moq framework when the repository code is not being executed ?

Comment: Where are you giving `mockRepository` the `mockContext`??

Comment: Why would you mock the context out, when you have already mocked the repository out. The very nature of mocking is saying, forget everything but this one method I'm using, `This method needs to give me this data`. In those circumstances there is no need to worry about the context.

Comment: @CallumLinington I need the data to be flowing through the repository and return back the valid list of items. So I'm mocking the context as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you've mocked your repository, without seeing the Controller logic, I'm not sure why you would need to mock the dbContext. But effectively with this test you are testing the Controller logic and not the repository as you've mocked the repository and what is returned from the GetById in the repository.

If you wish to test the filter logic in the repository, you would need to mock the dbContext (as you have done) and in the test create a new concrete Repository instance and test the data that is returned from a call to GetById.

So you mock dbContext.MyModel, returning your three items and let the Where call perform the filtering.

There's plenty of useful information out there regarding use of a mocking framework, but everyone has slightly differing opinions about what you should test and small a unit you should test in a single unit test, experience and personal preference is the key here.

Comment: Should I remove mocking the repository ? I mean the `mockRepository.Setup`

Comment: Well it's valid to have a controller level test and given that you've mocked your repository your testing that the controller is simply returning straight from the repository. This may seem pointless but if someone modifies the controller logic in the future and breaks this, then you know that the controller logic is no longer just returning the data from your repository. I think you need a repository test as well and in this a repository test you can test your filtering logic. So in your controller test just mock the repository and in your repository test just mock the db context

Comment: I'm getting `Exception thrown: 'Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException' in Moq.dll` when passing the mocked context to concrete repo constructor. Any Idea ?

Comment: It is likely because you are mocking something that is not an interface, you could create an interface for your db context and inject that into your repository, then you can easily mock the db context

Comment: Appreciate your help. I'm on the integration testing side than on the unit testing with moq.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your test I would say there is very little benefit to using a mocking framework or even having this test.  My thoughts are:

1) If you have a repository write an integration test as you want to prove that you are returning data from the database/web service etc

2) Use Moq or RhinoMocks in situations where you want to test some business logic/behaviour

Comment: I'm setting the expectations prior to running the unit test (using `.Returns` method). So, I know the test would pass. What is the point of mocking everything when I know it just works.

Comment: Well you know this works using an IQueryable which is fine but when this talks to SQL certain commands in LINQ won't be available. Therefore it is always better to have integration tests for the repository side.

Answer (score 0):

with Unit tests you try to test/harden your Business logic. in your repositories should not be any BL (Businesslogic). with your MOCK Framework you disable think you don´t want to test. -> Repository = access to Data.
With this you are able to change your way you get your data (repository) without any changes on your Businesslogic/UnitTests :)

PS: if you want to test your Repositories or even more you should aim to integration tests or even to End to End tests.